# Разбор XML

Tags: c#, xml

Имеется XML вида:

```
<response>
<header>
<status>0</status>
<query>content:1</query>
</header>
<result name="response" numFound="252" collapsedDocCount="0" start="0" rows="10" maxScore="1.4509346" time="1">
<doc score="1.4509346" pos="0">...</doc>
<doc score="0.667432" pos="1">...</doc>
<doc score="0.6583509" pos="2">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5966812" pos="3">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5966812" pos="4">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5873755" pos="5">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5865056" pos="6">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5865056" pos="7">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5625564" pos="8">...</doc>
<doc score="0.5625564" pos="9">...</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Как выдернуть оттуда в ListBox значения (numFound,maxScore, score ...)?

Comment: @IGOR, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте примеры [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/by2bd43b.aspx) по XmlReader ну и свой кусочек кода в пример:

```
   using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(progressStreamWrapper))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                if (reader.Name.Equals("result"))
                                {
                                     var t = reader.GetAttribute("maxScore")
...
```