# Индекс за пределами диапазона C# XPath

Tags: c#, xpath

При парсе с html информацию, появляется ошибка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
>   Имя параметра: index"

```
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(textBox1.Text);


        var c = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[7]/table[1]/tbody");

        var tableElements = new List<ReadOnlyCollection<string>>();

        if (c != null)
        {
            var time = c.SelectNodes("//tr[@id]/td[1]/text()");
            var info = c.SelectNodes("//tr[@id]/td[2]/text()");
            var cob = c.SelectNodes("//tr[@id]/td[4]/a/text()");

            var vact = c.SelectNodes("//tr/td[5]/text()");
            var Prog = c.SelectNodes("//tr/td[6]/text()");
            var Pred = c.SelectNodes("//tr/td[7]/span/text()");

            int m = 0;
            do
            {
                var tableRow = new List<string>();
                tableRow.Add(time[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(info[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(cob[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(vact[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableElements.Add(tableRow.AsReadOnly());
            } while (m < info.Count);

            foreach (var row in tableElements)
            {
                var FACT = "";
                if (row[3] == "&nbsp;")
                    FACT = "НЕТУ";
                else FACT = row[3];
                if (row[0] != "Экономический календарь")
                    textBox1.Text += "Text" + row[0] + " Страна " + row[1] + "Text" + row[2] + " Факт " + FACT +  Environment.NewLine;
                else
                    textBox1.Text += "Нуль";
            }
        }
```

Собственно ссылка на сайт [https://ru.investing.com/economic-calendar/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

По моим наблюдения, думаю, что это из за первого

> [tr][/tr]

Потому, что в нем содержится информация только о дате, а вот следующий

> [tr][/tr]

Уже имеет нужную инфу
Скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос, как исправить ситуацию ?

Я уже пытался удалить, первый [tr], но по методам Remove(); но не получилось (

Comment: Итерируйтесь по tr и каждый раз ищите относительно него элементы.

Comment: А аккаунт новый зачем создавать то? Задавали вроде [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837817/Получение-данных-подклассов-xml-c) о работе с данным сайтом с одного аккаунта, а потом вдруг решили новый сделать, зачем? Ну а так, по вопросу... Вы бьете "в лоб", то есть у вас все статично, скажем тут `@"/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[7]/table[1]/tbody`, выбираем первый html, первый body, а потом 5-й div, а если их будет вдруг 10? Ищите по классам, по тем данным, что не меняются!

Comment: Ответ как парсить этот сайт [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843259/222542)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря, не совсем вник в код, но все же сделаю предположение:
Нет ли тут ошибки?

```
            do
            {
                var tableRow = new List<string>();
                tableRow.Add(time[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(info[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(cob[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(vact[m++].InnerText.Trim());
                tableElements.Add(tableRow.AsReadOnly());
            } while (m < info.Count);
```

Может быть m нужно увеличивать один раз в итерацию цикла? Иначе вы бежите по коллекциям "по диагонали"

```
            do
            {
                var tableRow = new List<string>();
                tableRow.Add(time[m].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(info[m].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(cob[m].InnerText.Trim());
                tableRow.Add(vact[m].InnerText.Trim());
                tableElements.Add(tableRow.AsReadOnly());
                m++;
            } while (m < info.Count);
```

Извините за тривиальный ответ, возможно я не разобрался в контексте.

Comment: тогда уж `m++;` в конец надо, а не в начало

Comment: @tym32167 совершенно верно замечено, поправил

Comment: @NaivE Тогда, по логике, первый проход будет произведен по tr, которая имеет только текст. Значит если присудить int m= 1; то, при парсер мы сразу попадаем на tr который имеет класс, и так прыгаем дальше

Answer (score 3):

Как по мне вы используете совершенно не правильный подход. Вы все прибиваете гвоздями, делаете статичное. То есть вы говорите "Я хочу 5-ый объект, который находится в первом body", а если объект будет не 5-ый, а скажем 10, или он переместится вовсе в какой нибудь div? Тогда все, вам придется очень многое переделывать и заново искать эти объекты, это не эффективно!

Я вот сделал небольшую "вырезку" с того сайта, давайте по ней попробуем что то получить...

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="eCalNew eCalMainNew ecoCalCont">
         <div id="div-gpt-ad-1370187203350-ec1" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px;"></div>
         <div id="ecoCalTabsMenu" class="ecoCalTabs dirLtr">
            <ul class="float_lang_base_1 tabsForBox" id="ecoCalTabsTop">
               <li class="first selected"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Экономический календарь</a></li>
               <li><a href="/holiday-calendar/">Праздники</a></li>
               <li><a href="/earnings-calendar/">Отчёты</a></li>
               <li><a href="/dividends-calendar/">Дивиденды</a></li>
               <li><a href="/stock-split-calendar/">Сплиты</a></li>
               <li><a href="/ipo-calendar/">IPO</a></li>
               <li class="last"><a href="/futures-expiration-calendar/">Фьючерсы</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="js-notification-bar notification notificationImportant ">
            <span class="iconHolder"><i class="importantIcon"></i></span>
            <span class="alertText js-open-auth-trigger-inside" data-page-type="sml" data-ga-event-label="Calendars"><a onclick="overlay.overlayLogin();" href="javascript:void(0);" class="bold">Войдите</a> / <a onclick="overlay.overlayRegister();" href="javascript:void(0);" class="bold">зарегистрируйтесь бесплатно</a> для сохранения выбранных фильтров.</span>
            <i class="bugCloseIcon js-notification-bar-close"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         <table id="economicCalendarData" class="genTbl closedTbl ecoCalTbl persistArea">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th class="first time left">Время </th>
                  <th class="flagCur left">Валюта</th>
                  <th class="textNum imp left">Важн.</th>
                  <th class="event left">Событие</th>
                  <th class="act">Факт.</th>
                  <th class="time">Прогноз</th>
                  <th class="prev">Пред.</th>
                  <th class="last"></th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody pagestartat="">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="9" class="theDay" id="theDay1528329600">Четверг, 7 июня 2018 г.</td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="eventRowId_367319" class="js-event-item" event_attr_id="349" data-event-datetime="2018/06/07 01:30:00">
                  <td class="first left time js-time" title="Данные вышли 15ч 49м назад">01:30</td>
                  <td class="left flagCur noWrap"><span title="Австралия" class="ceFlags Australia" data-img_key="Australia">&nbsp;</span> AUD</td>
                  <td class="left textNum sentiment noWrap" title="Низкая волатильность" data-img_key="bull1"><i class="grayFullBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i></td>
                  <td class="left event" title="Для получения дополнительной информации нажмите здесь"><a href="/economic-calendar/aig-construction-index-349" target="_blank">
                     Индекс активности в сфере строительства от AIG  (май)</a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="bold act blackFont event-367319-actual" title="" id="eventActual_367319">54,0</td>
                  <td class="fore  event-367319-forecast " id="eventForecast_367319">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="prev blackFont  event-367319-previous" id="eventPrevious_367319"><span title="">55,4</span></td>
                  <td class="alert js-injected-user-alert-container " data-name="Индекс активности в сфере строительства от AIG" data-event-id="349" data-status-enabled="0">
                     <span class="alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Создать уведомление" data-tooltip-alt="Уведомление активно"></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="eventRowId_368093" class="js-event-item revised" event_attr_id="987" data-event-datetime="2018/06/07 02:50:00">
                  <td class="first left time js-time" title="Данные вышли 14ч 29м назад">02:50</td>
                  <td class="left flagCur noWrap"><span title="Япония" class="ceFlags Japan" data-img_key="Japan">&nbsp;</span> JPY</td>
                  <td class="left textNum sentiment noWrap" title="Низкая волатильность" data-img_key="bull1"><i class="grayFullBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i><i class="grayEmptyBullishIcon"></i></td>
                  <td class="left event" title="Для получения дополнительной информации нажмите здесь"><a href="/economic-calendar/foreign-bonds-buying-987" target="_blank">
                     Объём покупок иностранных облигаций </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="bold act blackFont event-368093-actual" title="" id="eventActual_368093">-1.665,8B</td>
                  <td class="fore  event-368093-forecast " id="eventForecast_368093">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="prev greenFont  event-368093-previous" id="eventPrevious_368093"><span title="Пересмотрено с -717,0B">-700,2B</span></td>
                  <td class="alert js-injected-user-alert-container " data-name="Объём покупок иностранных облигаций" data-event-id="987" data-status-enabled="0">
                     <span class="alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Создать уведомление" data-tooltip-alt="Уведомление активно"></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Что мы здесь видим? Хм, ну у нас есть объект table с уникальным ID economicCalendarData, по сути нам этого достаточно для того, что бы вытянуть уже этот объект, попробуем?

```
var calendarData = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='economicCalendarData']");
```

Заметьте, я здесь просто указал, что хочу один объект table, id которого = economicCalendarData. Результатом мне выдаст нужный объект для дальнейшей работы.

Отлично, идем дальше! Наша таблица содержит в себе tbody, внутри которого находится куча полезных для нас tr. Что есть примечательного в tr? Правильно, класс, все нужные нам данные помечены классом js-event-item, некоторые содержать дополнительно и другие классы (например revised), по этому нам надо использовать в xpath условие "содержит". Давайте попробуем:

```
var tableRow = calendarData.SelectNodes(".//tbody//tr[contains(@class,'js-event-item')]");
```

И тут все довольно просто, я вызываю метод `SelectNodes` для получения множества результатов. В Xpath задаю, что хочу в указанном объекте (точка в начале) получить tbody, а в нем получить все tr, класс которых содержит js-event-item. Все, результатом в моем примере будет 2 объекта tr.
**!** Тут хочу сделать предупреждение! Не забывайте делать проверку на NULL, ибо мы можем к примеру не получить table в первом запросе, что выдаст нам NULL, без проверок все упадет!

Ну все, что нам осталось? Получить данные? Ну, а это пусть будет вашим домашним заданием, там все точно также, получаем нужные td, ну и работаем с ними..

В общем вот вам простейший подход к поставленной задаче. Удачи в программирование!

Comment: Отличный ответ. Отмечу, что элемент можно получить по `id` следующим образом: `var calendarData = htmlDocument.GetElementbyId("economicCalendarData");`. Конечно, при этом должно соблюдаться требование, что `id` уникален.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо. Да, вы правы, я данным ответом хотел показать как работать именно с XPath, по этому данные методы не упоминал.